# Algorithm to delete a node from the middle

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, nodes

I'm reading Cracking the Coding Interview and doing practice problems and I'm stuck on this one:

"Implement an algorithm to delete a node in the middle (i.e., any node but the first and the last node, not necessarily the exact middle) or a singly linked list, given only access to that node.

EXAMPLE
Input: the node  from the linked list a->b->c->d->e->f
Result: nothing is returned, but the new linked list looks like a->b->d->e->f"

Here's my code :

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None, nextnode = None):
        self.data = data
        self.nextnode = nextnode

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.nextnode = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def remove(self, data):
        current = self.head
        absent = True
        if current == None: print('List is empty')
        if current.data == data:
            self.head = current.nextnode
            absent = False
        while current.nextnode:
            if current.nextnode.data == data:
                absent = False
                if current.nextnode.nextnode:
                    current.nextnode = current.nextnode.nextnode
                else: current.nextnode = None
            else: current = current.nextnode
        if absent: print('Element not in list')

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        size = 0
        while current:
            current = current.nextnode
            size += 1
        return size

    def find(self, data):
        current = self.head
        if current == None: print('List is empty')
        search = True
        while current and search:
            if current.data == data:
                print(current)
                search = False
            current = current.nextnode
        if search: print('Not found')

def print_list(self):
    current = self.head
    while current:
        print(current, end = ' ')
        current = current.nextnode
    print('')    


node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3)
node4 = Node(4)
node1.nextnode = node2
node2.nextnode = node3
node3.nextnode = node4
list1 = LinkedList(node1)
list1.insert(2 ****EDITED node2 to 2 here****)
print_list(list1)

def delmid(ll, n):
    current = ll.head
    if current == n:
        print('Can\'t delete first node')
        return
    while current.nextnode:
        if current.nextnode == n:
            if current.nextnode.nextnode:
                current.nextnode = current.nextnode.nextnode
                return
            else:
                print('Can\'t delete last node')
                return

delmid(list1, node2)
print_list(list1)
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't seem to think that ll.head and node2 are the same ... It does work if I get rid of the line `list1.insert(node2)` ...

I don't understand ...

EDIT: after reading the first sentence of the solution in the book, apparently i did it wrong anyways .... "given only access to that node" means you don't know the head of the list ... back to the drawing board ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your insert method is wrong:

```
def insert(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.nextnode = self.head
    self.head = new_node
```

Your method does not **insert `node2` itself** as a node: it creates a **new node** with `node2` as payload (data). That is something different.

You can define a method:

```
def insert_node(self, node):
    node.nextnode = self.head
    self.head = new_node
```

Nevertheless this will **create a loop** since now `node1` will be pointing to `node2` and node2`to`node1`. So the resulting linked list will be a rounded list with two elements, like:

```
node1  -->  node2
  ^---------/
```

**EDIT**: since you solved that one. There is also a problem with your `delmid` method.

The main problem is that **in your `while` loop** you need to walk through the linked list, and you do not do that: current always remains the same, so:

```
def delmid(ll, n):
    current = ll.head
    if current == n:
        print('Can\'t delete first node')
        return
    while current.nextnode:
        if current.nextnode == n:
            if current.nextnode.nextnode:
                current.nextnode = current.nextnode.nextnode
                return
            else:
                print('Can\'t delete last node')
                return
        current = current.nextnode
```

Should fix that.

Comment: oh, sorry, my initial code had `list1.insert(2)` instead of `list1.insert(node2)`, and it still wasn't working, so i was in the process of changing it to see is maybe after inserting "2" it's still not considered a node even tho it's now part of a linked list

Comment: @Raksha: well the problem in your `delmid` is that you do not walk through the linked list.

Comment: ooooooooooh, i just got what was wrong while typing up a question ... I was gonna say "so ignoring the delmid function, would `list1.insert(2)` not result in `list1.head` == node2` ?" and that would depend on what `list1.head.nextnode` is, wouldn't it ..... since node2.nextnode = node3, so anything other than 3 would make them not equal

Comment: @Raksha: no `insert(2)` will create a **new node** that also happens to have **the value 2**, but there are thus two different nodes with value `2` now.

Comment: but isn't any node with value 2 and nextnode = node3 same as node2?

Comment: no, the idea is that there can be thousands of objects that have the same values and next nodes, etc. But after a while you can change one/some of them, and the others still will contain the old data and refer to the old nodes

Answer (score 0):

### Insert operation

You misunderstood your own `insert`-implementation. 
`list1.insert(node2)` inserts a new node with `node2` as **content**:

```
def insert(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)    #  <== wrap node2 into another node instance
    new_node.nextnode = self.head
    self.head = new_node
```

### Comparison of Nodes

The `==`-operator internally works by calling the method `__eq__(self, other)`. In your case you didn't provide and implementation for this method, so the default is used to compare by **all** variables, which includes `nextnode`. Thus two nodes can only be equal, if they are precisely the same. To get this corrected, use a custom comparison method in `Node`:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other) is Node && other.data == self.data
```

This `__eq__`-method would work by first checking that `other` definitely is of type `Node` and afterwards compare by the `data` stored in each instance.

### Delmid

Going a bit further than the actual question:

```
while current.nextnode:
    if current.nextnode == n:
        if current.nextnode.nextnode:
            current.nextnode = current.nextnode.nextnode
            return
        else:
            print('Can\'t delete last node')
            return
```

This loop will run infinitely, unless the list has at most a size of 1. To fix this step through the list by `current = current.nextnode`.

### Improving Delmid

The actual purpose of this task was to get you used to another way of manipulating linked lists: **swapping**.

Instead of searching the entire list for the predecessor of `n`, you could just check that `n` is neither the first nor the last node, swap out the value with the value of it's consecutive node and delete the consecutive node:

```
def delmid(ll, n):
    if ll.head == n:
        print('Can\'t delete first node')
        return
    if n.nextnode is None:
        print('Can\'t delete last node')
        return

    # swap values
    tmp = n.data
    n.data = n.nextnode.data
    n.nextnode.data = tmp

    # remove node
    n.nextnode = n.nextnode.nextnode
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting everyone confused now, including myself %\ ... my initial code had list1.insert(2) instead of list1.insert(node2), and it still wasn't working, so i was in the process of changing it to see if maybe after inserting "2" it's still not considered a node even tho it's now part of a linked list. And yeah, the function is currently broken in several places, I was just trying to work out one problem at a time

Comment: @Raksha I've just noticed that during testing. I'll add an explanation on how to solve that issue.

Comment: i think i just answered my own question .... `list1.head == node2` only in a list where the second node is the same as `node2.nextnode = node3` ... lemme test that real quick ...

Comment: @Raksha pretty much, yup. Already pointed that out in my answer, including a solution

Comment: yeah, i always forget to put in `current = current.nextnode` >.< ..... and thanks for the tip, that does make the function neater :)